# iOS SpriteKit animation not working

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, sprite-kit

I am new to the iOS native game development. I am trying to create animation using some frames for Ideal state for the character. I am following tutorial from the [Ray's Website](https://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases). Look like I am doing everything fine but I can't see animation in working. Only first frame (default) is visible all the time. I debug the code & it's indeed visiting blinking player method where all 3 frames are also present, but nothing happening on screen.

It will be great if someone can guide/help me identify the issue.

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    NSArray *_playerBlinkFrames;
}

// Player
SKNode *_player;

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        [self createPlayer];    
}
    return self;
}

- (void) createPlayer
{
    SKTextureAtlas *playerAnimatedAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Assets"];
    _player = [SKNode node];
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Idle"];
    [_player addChild:sprite];

    [sprite setName:@"Ball"];

    NSMutableArray *blinkFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

    SKTexture *temp = [playerAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:@"Idle.png"];
    SKTexture *temp2 = [playerAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:@"Blink.png"];
    SKTexture *temp3 = [playerAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:@"LookRight.png"];


    [blinkFrames addObject:temp];
    [blinkFrames addObject:temp2];
    [blinkFrames addObject:temp3];

    _playerBlinkFrames = blinkFrames;
    _player.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:_player];
    [self blinkingPlayer];
}

-(void)blinkingPlayer
{
    [_player runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
                      [SKAction animateWithTextures:_playerBlinkFrames
                                       timePerFrame:0.3f
                                             resize:NO
                                            restore:YES]] withKey:@"blinkingInPlacePlayer"];

    return;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Player
SKSpriteNode *_player;

//..//
SKTextureAtlas *playerAnimatedAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Assets"];

NSMutableArray *blinkFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

SKTexture *temp = [playerAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:@"Idle.png"];
SKTexture *temp2 = [playerAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:@"Blink.png"];
SKTexture *temp3 = [playerAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:@"LookRight.png"];


[blinkFrames addObject:temp];
[blinkFrames addObject:temp2];
[blinkFrames addObject:temp3];

_playerBlinkFrames = blinkFrames;

SKTexture *tempSprite = _playerBlinkFrames[0];
_player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tempSprite];
```

I've not tested it, but i think you have create a SKNode player covered by a spritenode.

let me know

Comment: Yes you are right, I was following it from one of the tutorial on you tube. this in deed works well. I also changed the way I am initializing the object in the intiWithSize function       _player = [self createNewPlayer];
        [self addChild:_player];